# Adding data of type dynamic to dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a code like this:

```
private void CreateRecord(dynamic dealerData, string methodVerb)
{

     var sample = new MarketData()
     {
        Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

     }
}
```

I want to add dealerData to dictionary at runtime.

Can this dictionary initialization be used like this:

```
Parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(dealerData);
```

Also, I want to add one more line to this dictionary at runtime. 
This is: "Verb", "PUT".

Comment: We need an example of what 'dealerData' contains to give you the best possible answer.

Comment: @DanielleSummers Suppose it contains two column data.

Comment: What is the reason for dealerData to be dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided, it seems like it would be easier - and better practice - to deserialize your Json into a data model. The concept you've come up with doesn't seem to be suited to holding the information you want in an easily usable way.

However, if you insist on pursuing this method, I'll assume your Json looks like:

```
{ "property1": "value1", "property2": "value2" }
```

You can deserialize your Json to a Dictionary like this:

```
Parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(dealerData);
Parameters.Add("Verb", methodVerb);
```

If your Json isn't in this format, you'll have to let me know and I'll update my answer.